# 'ValueError: optimizing a parameter that doesn't require gradients' do not understand the error

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, artificial-intelligence

as a part of an online python course, I am developing a an AI program that can identify flowers. After my first submission, I was told that I forgot to freeze the parameters after loading the model so the aren't modified during backprop. To solve this, in the block where I load my model I did this:

```
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")model = models.vgg16(pretrained = True)    
model
for param in model.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False
```

Then, when running the block where I define a new feedforward (code block below, I get the error   'ValueError: optimizing a parameter that doesn't require gradients'

```
features = list(model.classifier.children())[:-1]

num_filters = model.classifier[len(features)].in_features
features.extend([
    nn.Linear(25088, 2048),
    nn.ReLU(True),
    nn.Linear(2048, 512),
    nn.ReLU(True),
    nn.Linear(512, 102),
    nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1)
])

model.classifier = nn.Sequential(*features)
criterion = nn.NLLLoss()
model = model.to('cuda')
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.classifier.parameters(), lr = 0.001)
model
```

I'd be great if anyone could help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You try to optimize frozen parameters. You must pass to optimizer only parameters that you want optimize, where requires_grad = True not all.

```
params_to_update = []
for name, param in model.named_parameters():
    if param.requires_grad == True:
        params_to_update.append(param)
optimizer = optim.Adam(params_to_update, lr = 0.001)
```

See tutorial: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/transfer_learning_tutorial.html#finetuning-the-convnet

Only parameters of fc layer passed to optimizer.